# Did something happen to uploaded profile pictures?

Tags: discussion, profile-picture, gravatar

I noticed my profile picture is a gravatar again.  No worries for me, but did something happen to the uploaded pictures?  DID NEFARIOUS HACKERS STEAL MY FACE???

Comment: Yes. Or no. Maybe. I still have mine...

Comment: They need it to go with the rest of your stolen identity?

Comment: Do you have that gravatar associated with the new email address you entered?

Comment: Bingo Jon!  That's it, thanks.

Comment: Your face broke gravatar.

Comment: Thanks Will, just what we need... web services with artistic opinions!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Jon Clements nailed it.  I changed my email address, which gravatar.com uses to identify the user.  My face is safely out of the hands of nefarious hackers (or maybe not!).

Comment: Good thing you are leaving an open ending, when is the sequel?

Comment: My fear is that the nefarious hackers will cause the downfall of civilization by POSTING MY FACE EVERY WEBSITE IN THE WORLD!

Comment: I would advise all websites of the world to block your face, but then they need your face on file to know which to block. Its unstoppable.

Comment: I wouldn't be worried about some nefarious hackers right now.  Facebook will link you to everything with their auto face matching AI.